# Eigenvalues of $N^T M N$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, block-matrices

let the matrices $M, N \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite, and $M$ is a lower block diagonal matrix. Consider the matrix $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

$$ T = N^T M N .$$

Can I say something about the boundedness of the eigenvalues of the matrix $T$? I know they are bounded from below by zero, but I'm searching for an upper bound for the eigenvalues. Can I maybe use the eigenvalues of M for that?

This does not look like a new or unstudied problem. Does someone know some references?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "lower block diagonal"?

Comment: If $M$ is symmetric and positive definite, then we have the upper bound $\lambda_{\max}(M) \cdot \sigma_{\max}^2(M)$, where $\lambda_{\max}$ and $\sigma_{\max}$ denote the maximal eigenvalue and singular value.

Comment: Denote the largest absolute value of an eigenvector by $\rho$, then you have $\rho(AB) \leq \rho(A)*\rho(B)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann by lower block diagonal I meant lower block triangular, sorry for the mistake. I meant $M$ = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ B & C \end{pmatrix}

Comment: @chickenNinja123 Thank you, that is exactly what I am searching for! Do you have a reference where I can see the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just realised that your $M$ is not symmetric, so the above equation might not hold. Typically, when people say "positive definite" they implicitly talk about symmetric matrices.

Comment: In any case: for any matrix norm $\| . \|$ we have $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \|B\|$. Given a (vector) norm on your original space (like the usual euclidean norm) this induces a so called operator norm on matrices. Any such operator norm $\| . \|_O$ dominates the spectral radius, i.e. $\rho(A) \leq \|A\|_O$. For normal matrices $N$ (i.e. matrices that satisfy $NN^T = N^TN$) the operator norm induced by the euclidean norm is exactly the spectral radius. So, if your matrices are normal (and symmetric matrices are) then maximal eigenvector inequality described in my previous comment holds.